# behavior of arrow function vs normal function in onPress method

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

'm learning native react and learning more about javascript, so I still do not understand many things about its behavior. I have created a button component, using TouchableOpacity, and its props onPress.
For it to work, I must send the function I want to execute as a props, but here I have fallen due to my little experience.

I am sending a console.log that is activated when I press the button. So I passed the console.log directly in the props that I defined, but it did not work when I clicked on the button, but, it was executed when the code is initialized. On the other hand, when I have passed an arrow function that contains the console.log, it has been executed at the moment of clicking the button.

to make it clearer I'll show my code:

this is my button component:

```
const Button = ({ onUserPress, children, color }) => {

    const state = {

    };
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ onUserPress } style={styles.buttonStyle} >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

and i call them like this:

```
<Button onUserPress={ console.log("hello") }>Something</Button>
```

This is executed at the time of initializing my application, and nothing is happened when the button is pressed.

on the other hand, when i use the same component, but i pass the console.log in arrow function, like this:

```
<Button onUserPress={ ()=>{console.log("hello")} }>Something</Button>
```

this execute the console log only when i press the button component.

Could someone explain to me why the behavior is different? The world of functional programming is totally new to me and these things seem strange to me. According to what I understand, both are functions, so for me they do not make a difference (obviously, from my ignorant point of view). What is the difference that makes the behavior different?

Comment: `console.log("hello") ` is  a function call in it.. `()=>{console.log("hello")}` is a function definition

Comment: The first one looks like a typo. I don't think it was intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't comparing a "normal function" with an arrow function.

The content between `{` and `}` is an *expression* which is evaluated and the result is assigned to the prop.

Thus you are calling `console.log("hello")`, taking the *return value* and assigning that as a function to `onUserPress` (this makes no sense as the return value of `console.log` is not a function).

---

Not a function:

```js
console.log("hello");
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this solves a part of my doubt, but I still do not understand why when I pass consol.log directly it is executed when starting, whereas when I pass it in an arrow function, it is executed only when I trigger the event?

Comment: @kmilo93sd — If you console.log something, then it logs it immediately. If you write a function that console.logs something, then it logs something *when the function is called*.

Comment: but why the arrow function is executed afterwards and not at the moment like when I pass it directly? because that function is not executed at that moment? I understand that console.log is also a function, which does not return value, I understand that, but the form of arrow function is also a function, what is it that makes it run afterwards and not at the moment of starting the app? What is causing that behavior? If I directly execute a function of my own that if I return a value, it is also executed on startup, the console.log was just an example. sorry my bad english please.

Comment: "but why the arrow function is executed afterwards and not at the moment like when I pass it directly?" — Because it isn't called until the event fires.

Comment: "I understand that console.log is a function" — `console.log` is, `console.log("Hello")` is not.

Comment: Oh perfect, now I understand, thank you very much for the patience and the love when responding. this solves the doubts I had, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want use arrow function you need to pass a regular function: `onUserPress={ function(){console.log("hello")}`.

Also, you can pass `onUserPress={console.log}`, in this case, `console.log` will receive an event object as a parameter.

Difference in `function(){console.log("hello")` and `() => console.log("hello")` that in second case "this" will be pointed to your component

Answer (score 0):

```
1-> <Button onUserPress={ console.log("hello") }>Something</Button>
2-> <Button onUserPress={ () => console.log("hello") }>Something</Button>
```

**in first : you're calling the console.log("hello") ,
where as in 2nd you're returning console.log("hello")**

so its  similar to

> const functionCall = ()=>{
> do something...
> }
>
> ```
>     const x = document.getElementById("root")
>     x.addEventListener("click",functionCall())  <--- WRONG!!!
> ```
>
> in the above case it will CALL the function,even before you press the
> input/button which is "called" inside the 2nd parameter.
>
> **Rather**
>
> x.addEventListener("click",functionCall) <---- Correct    it executes
> the function when you click the button/input