# Is there a reason why React re-render immediately although there is another state update inside of an async operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Notable reference: [Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949393/cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-component)

My goal is to better understand how React re-render whether on every state update or after all of the state is updated.

My current understanding is `React re-render on every state update` which will cause `Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component` if you have 2 state update `one outside of an async operation, and one inside`. This error happens if you update a state and then do another state update inside async operation `try, catch, finally`.

Example with `Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component` because React does not wait to re-render although there is a state update inside the async operation. The current fix is not to do a state update.

features/Home/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Camera from '../../components/camera';
import {SafeAreaView, TouchableHighlight, Image} from 'react-native';

export default function Home() {
  const [img, setImg] = React.useState(null);

  function onPicture({uri}) {
    setImg(uri);
  }

  function onBackToCamera() {
    setImg(null);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        {img ? (
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{flex: 1}}
            onPress={() => onBackToCamera()}>
            <Image source={{uri: img}} style={{flex: 1}} />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        ) : (
          <Camera onPicture={onPicture} />
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
}
```

components/camera.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';
import {TouchableOpacity, Alert, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default function Camera({onPicture}) {
  let camera;
  const [isTakingPicture, setTakePicture] = React.useState(false);
  
  async function takePicture() {
    if (camera && !isTakingPicture) {
      let options = {
        quality: 0.85,
        fixOrientation: true,
        forceUpOrientation: true,
      };

      setTakePicture(true);

      try {
        const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        // Alert.alert('Success', JSON.stringify(data));
        onPicture(data);
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to take picture: ' + (err.message || err));
        return;
      } finally {
        setTakePicture(false);
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <RNCamera
      ref={(ref) => (camera = ref)}
      captureAudio={false}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
      androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use camera',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.5}
        style={styles.btnAlignment}
        onPress={takePicture}>
        <Icon name="camera" size={50} color="#fff" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </RNCamera>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  btnAlignment: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to explain about the re-render and the warning. I will start why re-render happens in your code.

So, you call the `onBackToCamera` function inside the `onPress` handler and that's why re-render is occupied immediately. To avoid it, you should rewrite the `onPress` handler.

Before:

```
onPress={() => onBackToCamera()}>
```

After:

```
onPress={onBackToCamera}>
```

You see this warning `Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component` because during updating your state of `Home` Component you replace `null` with HTTP response.

I will try to explain step by step how to appear this warning in the console.

1. The `Camera` component is shown before calling the `takePicture` function as the `img` is `null`.
2. Then you update the state inside the `try` block replacing null value with HTTP response data.
3. After updating, the `TouchableHighlight` component is shown instead of the `Camera` one because the `img` value doesn't equal to null.
4. Now, the `Camera` component has been unmounted but the `takePicture` function isn't finished its execution and you try to update the state of the unmounted component in `finally` block.

The last action causes `Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component`

Comment: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652908/behavior-of-arrow-function-vs-normal-function-in-onpress-method) Could you please explain why `() => onBackToCamera()` vs `onBackToCamera` makes a difference?